# Postgres function slower than same ad hoc query

Tags: postgresql

I have had several cases where a Postgres function that returns a table result from a query is much slower than running the actual query. Why is that?

This is one example, but I've found that function is slower than just the query in many cases.

```
create function trending_names(date_start timestamp with time zone, date_end timestamp with time zone, gender_filter character, country_filter text)
    returns TABLE(name_id integer, gender character, country text, score bigint, rank bigint)
    language sql
as
$$
select u.name_id,
       n.gender,
       u.country,
       count(u.rank)                                   as score,
       row_number() over (order by count(u.rank) desc) as rank
from babynames.user_scores u
         inner join babynames.names n on u.name_id = n.id
where u.created_at between date_start and date_end
  and u.rank > 0
  and n.gender = gender_filter
  and u.country = country_filter
group by u.name_id, n.gender, u.country
$$;
```

This is the query plan for a select from the function:

```
Function Scan on trending_names  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=84) (actual time=1118.673..1118.861 rows=2238 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=216509 read=29837
Planning Time: 0.078 ms
Execution Time: 1119.083 ms
```

Query plan from just running the query. This takes less than half the time.

```
WindowAgg  (cost=44834.98..45593.32 rows=43334 width=25) (actual time=383.387..385.223 rows=2238 loops=1)
Planning Time: 2.512 ms
Execution Time: 387.403 ms
  Buffers: shared hit=100446 read=50220
  ->  Sort  (cost=44834.98..44943.31 rows=43334 width=17) (actual time=383.375..383.546 rows=2238 loops=1)
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 271kB
        Sort Key: (count(u.rank)) DESC
        Buffers: shared hit=100446 read=50220
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=41064.22..41497.56 rows=43334 width=17) (actual time=381.088..381.906 rows=2238 loops=1)
"              Group Key: u.name_id, u.country, n.gender"
              Buffers: shared hit=100446 read=50220
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=5352.15..40630.88 rows=43334 width=13) (actual time=60.710..352.646 rows=36271 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (u.name_id = n.id)
                    Buffers: shared hit=100446 read=50220
                    ->  Index Scan using user_scores_rank_ix on user_scores u  (cost=0.43..35077.55 rows=76796 width=11) (actual time=24.193..287.393 rows=69770 loops=1)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=5005.89..5005.89 rows=27667 width=6) (actual time=36.420..36.420 rows=27472 loops=1)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 106521
                          Index Cond: (rank > 0)
                          Filter: ((created_at >= '2021-01-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (country = 'sv'::text) AND (created_at <= now()))
                          Buffers: shared hit=99417 read=46856
                          Buffers: shared hit=1029 read=3364
                          Buckets: 32768  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1330kB
                          ->  Seq Scan on names n  (cost=0.00..5005.89 rows=27667 width=6) (actual time=0.022..24.447 rows=27472 loops=1)
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 21559
                                Filter: (gender = 'f'::bpchar)
                                Buffers: shared hit=1029 read=3364
```

I'm also confused on why it does a Seq scan on names n in the last step since names.id is the primary key and gender is indexed.

Comment: Use `auto_explain` to capture the slow execution plan inside the function.

Comment: What if you declare the function as `stable`?

Comment: ```stable``` does seem to make it more of the same as the ad hoc query. Does this work even when the data changes frequently? The actual rows returned will change very often.

Comment: Yes, that's fine.  From the docs: `STABLE indicates that the function cannot modify the database, and that within a single table scan it will consistently return the same result for the same argument values, but that its result could change across SQL statements.`

Comment: Ok. The "consistently return the same result for the same argument values" sounded like I would always get the exact same rows for a single set of arguments. So I should think of it more like it can cache the query, rather than the result of the query?

Comment: With stable, the function can be [inlined](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions) effectively removing the function call completely and replacing it with the embedded query. It's like running the query (with parameters) directly. No "caching" involved"

Comment: Ok. Thanks for explanation. When I've had these problems I used ```with``` instead, so I guess a stable function and ```with``` becomes quite similar? (The results seems to be)